# Testing requests that have redirects in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test a `post` request that has a redirect if successful:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

I was wondering if it were at all possible to test to see if I receive a 201 response code before the redirect. Here is how I currently have my code. It will err because the redirect happens first:

```
RSpec.describe 'Posts', type: :request do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    it 'has a 201 response code' do
      post posts_path, params: { post: valid_attributes }

      expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You're response code with be a 302 since the post is being created successfully. In the example code you've been given you wont get a 201 back. You could check that you don't receive a 201: expect(response).to_not have_http_status(201).

Comment: So despite a new record having been created, I'll get the 302 instead since I explicitly wrote it in the controller? There's no order of execution in this case?

Comment: Creating a new Post model doesn't return an HTTP status code. It creates a row in the database. If you want to check that a post was created you could check that the count of posts is 0 at the start of the test and 1 at the end.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Thanks. Feel free to post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that a post was created and that a user was redirected, if params are valid. And if you have any validation in the Post model, it is good idea to test invalid params:

```
RSpec.describe 'PostsController', type: :request do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'with valid params' do
      it 'creates a new post' do
        expect { post posts_path, params: { post: valid_attributes } }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)        
        expect(response).to redirect_to post_path(Post.last)
      end
    end

    context 'with invalid params' do
      it 'does not create a new post' do
        expect { post posts_path, params: { post: invalid_attributes } }.not_to change(Post, :count)
        expect(response).to have_http_status 200
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You're response code will be a 302 since the post is being created successfully. In the example code you've been given you won't get a 201 back. You could check that you don't receive a 201

```
expect(response).to_not have_http_status(201).
```

Creating a new Post model doesn't return an HTTP status code. It creates a row in the database. If you want to check that a post was created you could check that the count of posts is 0 at the start of the test and 1 at the end.